# How to add polylines and annotations from user taps in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapbox, uigesturerecognizer, polyline

I am trying to drop annotations/pins wherever a user touches a certain location on the map. Whenever a user drops more 2 or more pins, it creates a polyline that connects the points. I got it to work in regular Swift 5, but I am trying to make it work in SwiftUI. I am using Mapbox. I am having trouble figuring out how to make it work with the coordinator. Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox

// Creates an annotation using title & coordinate
extension MGLPointAnnotation {
    convenience init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.init()
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}


// Represents & Displays an MGLMapView in SwiftUI
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    // Property binding to add annotations
    @Binding var annotations: [MGLPointAnnotation]
    //var mapView: MGLMapView!
    //var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

    
    // Creates a mapView with MGLMapView type
    private let mapView: MGLMapView = MGLMapView(frame: .zero, styleURL: MGLStyle.streetsStyleURL)

    // Needed function for UIViewRepresentable
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MGLMapView {
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        // Add a single tap gesture recognizer. This gesture requires the built-in MGLMapView tap gestures (such as those for zoom and annotation selection) to fail.
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleMapTap(sender:)))
        for recognizer in mapView.gestureRecognizers! where recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer {
            singleTap.require(toFail: recognizer)
        }
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
         
        // Convert `mapView.centerCoordinate` (CLLocationCoordinate2D) to screen location (CGPoint).
        let centerScreenPoint: CGPoint = mapView.convert(mapView.centerCoordinate, toPointTo: nil)
        print("Screen center: \(centerScreenPoint) = \(mapView.center)")
        
        return mapView
    }
    
    // Needed function for UIViewRepresentable
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MGLMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
            updateAnnotations()
            uiView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    }
    
    // Styles the map with a MapBox Studio URL
    func styleURL(_ styleURL: URL) -> MapView {
            mapView.styleURL = styleURL
            return self
    }
        
    // Specifies where the map is centered
    func centerCoordinate(_ centerCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MapView {
            mapView.centerCoordinate = centerCoordinate
            return self
    }
    
    // Specifies the zoom level of the initial view
    func zoomLevel(_ zoomLevel: Double) -> MapView {
            mapView.zoomLevel = zoomLevel
            return self
    }
    
    // Updates the annotations in the view
    private func updateAnnotations() {
        if let currentAnnotations = mapView.annotations {
            mapView.removeAnnotations(currentAnnotations)
        }
        mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    }
    
    // Makes the coordinater (coordinator class below)
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, mapView)
    }
    
    // A coordinator used with a delegate to add the annotation view to the map
    // A coordinator class is declared to implement and view MGLMapViewDelegate in SwiftUI
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MGLMapViewDelegate {
        var control: MapView
        var mapView: MGLMapView!
        var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
        var pointAnnotations = [MGLPointAnnotation]()


        init(_ control: MapView, _ mapView: MGLMapView) {
            self.control = control
            self.mapView = mapView
        }
        
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
            return nil
        }
        
        @objc func handleMapTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            // Convert tap location (CGPoint) to geographic coordinate (CLLocationCoordinate2D).
            let tapPoint: CGPoint = sender.location(in: mapView)
            let tapCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = mapView.convert(tapPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
            print("You tapped at: \(tapCoordinate.latitude), \(tapCoordinate.longitude)")
            
            // Create an array of coordinates for our polyline, starting at the center of the map and ending at the tap coordinate.
            //var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [mapView.centerCoordinate]
            coordinates.append(tapCoordinate)
            print("Coordinates list: \(coordinates)")

            
            //var pointAnnotations = [MGLPointAnnotation]()
            for coordinate in coordinates {
                let point = MGLPointAnnotation()
                point.coordinate = coordinate
                point.title = "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
                pointAnnotations.append(point)
                
                print("Annotations: \(pointAnnotations)")
                
                let polyline = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
                mapView.addAnnotation(polyline)
            
            }
            mapView.addAnnotations(pointAnnotations)
             
            // Remove any existing polyline(s) from the map.
            //if mapView.annotations?.count != nil, let existingAnnotations = mapView.annotations {
                //mapView.removeAnnotations(existingAnnotations)
            //}
             
            // Add a polyline with the new coordinates.
            //let polyline = MGLPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))
            //mapView.addAnnotation(polyline)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the single tap cannot work if making it 'to fail' for other recognisers, (I don't know why that happened in SwiftUI). Removing the for loop makes it work, but also disables other single tap features on the map, for example, annotations will not be clickable.

Therefore, I suggest using some other gesture instead, the following example is based on long press.

```
func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MGLMapView {
    mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    let longTap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleMapTap(sender:)))

    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longTap)
    
    return mapView
}
```

Second, the 'mapView' in the handler function should be 'control.mapView' according to the first line of your 'Coordinator' class.

```
@objc func handleMapTap(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        // Run the code unless user end the long press (Long press handler keep calling during press)
        //guard sender.state == .ended else { return }
        
        // Convert tap location (CGPoint) to geographic coordinate (CLLocationCoordinate2D).
        
        let locationInMap = sender.location(in: control.mapView)
        let coordinateSet = control.mapView.convert(locationInMap, toCoordinateFrom: nil)
        print("You tapped at: \(coordinateSet.latitude)")
        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            print("You final tapped at: \(coordinateSet.latitude)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced with the same issue with you.
I updated my library to the newest version and every thing worked!